# I am getting error FATAL EXCEPTION: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near “)”: syntax error (code 1?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am making News App and getting following error in my code.

I am getting following error in my database

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 1328
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near “)”: syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, title_description TEXT, author TEXT, );
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
    at com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp.ArticleSQLiteOpenHelper.onCreate(ArticleSQLiteOpenHelper.java:85)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:294)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
    at com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp.provider.BaseContentProvider.insert(BaseContentProvider.java:81)
    at com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp.provider.ArticleProvider.insert(ArticleProvider.java:68)
    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:267)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1539)
    at com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp.NewsDetailActivity$4.onClick(NewsDetailActivity.java:126)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Below my database class

```
public class ArticleSQLiteOpenHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE_FILE_NAME = "article.db";
    // @formatter:off
    public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + ArticleColumns.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + ArticleColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ArticleColumns.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ArticleColumns.TITLE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
            + ArticleColumns.AUTHOR + " TEXT, "+
            " );";
```

below my NewsDetailActivity code which I implemented content provider.

```
public class NewsDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton addToFavoritesBtn;
   Article article;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_details);


        Toolbar myChildToolbar =
                (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(myChildToolbar);

        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // Enable the Up button

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        final Article article = (Article) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("myDataKey");

        FloatingActionButton share = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.share_fab);
        ImageButton shareButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.share_button);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String articleDescription = article.getDescription() ;
                String articleTitle = article.getTitle();
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, articleDescription);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, articleTitle);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
            }
        });

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String articleDescription = article.getDescription() ;
                String articleTitle = article.getTitle();
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, articleDescription);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, articleTitle);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using"));
            }
        });
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article_title);
        final String articleTitle = article.getTitle();

        if (articleTitle != null) {
            textView.setText(articleTitle);
        }
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article_author);
        final String articleAuthor = article.getAuthor();


        if (articleAuthor != null) {
            textView1.setText(articleAuthor);
        }


        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.article_body);
        String articleDescription = article.getDescription();
        if (articleDescription != null) {
            textView2.setText(articleDescription);

        }
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.article_url);
        final String articleUrl = article.getUrl();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse(articleUrl));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Picasso.with(this).load(article.getUrlToImage()).into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo));

        addToFavoritesBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favorite_button);
        addToFavoritesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(ArticleColumns._ID, "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT"); //Value bro example 1
                values.put(ArticleColumns.TITLE, article.getTitle() ); // name
                values.put(ArticleColumns.TITLE_DESCRIPTION, article.getDescription());
                values.put(ArticleColumns.AUTHOR, article.getAuthor());

                getContentResolver().insert(ArticleColumns.CONTENT_URI, values);
            }
        });
    }
    //   String articlePublisheAt = article.getPublishedAt();
    // TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textPublisher);
    // if (articlePublisheAt != null) {
    //   textView3.setText(articlePublisheAt);
    //<TextView
    //     android:id="@+id/textPublisher"
    //   style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    // android:layout_width="match_parent"
    // android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    // android:textColor="#fff"
    //android:textStyle="bold"
    //android:textSize="20sp"
    //android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0.9"/>

    //}


}
```

### EDIT

After removing the **`,`** I now get the following error :-

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 28122 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20) at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method) –
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an additional comma (`,`) that you should remove, at the end of the line:

```
ArticleColumns.AUTHOR + " TEXT, "
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 25984

Comment: To narrow down the problem and making sure you're starting with a clean table creation, manually uninstall your app from your phone, and re-build and run your application.

Comment: what's the exception that you're getting exactly?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 26746
                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, title_description TEXT, author TEXT,  )

Comment: It very likely does not crash with the same error if you have both a) removed the extra comma and also b) uninstalled the App from the device (alternately you could clear the App's data). You should edit your question to include the log from this subsequent crash and additionally including any relevant code.

Comment: My current DB table public static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ARTICLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + ArticleColumns.TABLE_NAME + " ( "
            + ArticleColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + ArticleColumns.TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + ArticleColumns.TITLE_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
            + ArticleColumns.AUTHOR + " TEXT, "+
            " )";

Comment: You haven't removed the **`,`** after `author TEXT,)`.

Comment: @Mehdi B. I have done as you told me uninstalled app and clean reinstalled invalided cache restart not working

Comment: @EdgarSweden, as Mike pointed, you haven't removed the extra `,` at the end of the line.

Comment: @Mehdi B, FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.edgar.yodgorbekkomilo.newsapp, PID: 28122
                                                                                   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException: datatype mismatch (code 20)
                                                                                       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)

Comment: Yep that's because you have `values.put(ArticleColumns._ID, "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");` **_ID** column can not be a string. I'd suggest deleting or commenting out that line and let the rowid (**_ID** is an alias of the rowid) be automatically generated.

Comment: @EdgarSweden, again, as Mike said, you're trying to store a `String` within the `_ID` column. The `_ID` column only accepts `Integers` as per your Table creation query... Remove this Line from your code `values.put(ArticleColumns._ID, "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT");`

Comment: @MikeT it is working thank you how can make when user clicks to favorite button it should save a favorite article

Comment: @EdgarSweden please accept the answer. The "favorites" question is out of the scope of this post. I suggest you post a new question with your new requirement / issue.

Comment: @Mehdi B. Thank you so much for your answer I will make another post

Answer (score 0):

I see an extra "," at the create statement.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS article ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, title TEXT NOT NULL, title_description TEXT, author ***TEXT,*** );

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: I was mentioning about the extra "," after the column author TEXT